# Upload folder over laravel api using flutter

Tags: laravel, flutter, directory, mobile-application, laravel-api

I want to upload a directory over laravel api without compressing the directory, I want to select the directory and upload it, is there any way to do it?

I searched too much for it but I didn't find any solution.
Is this possible?

Comment: I would suggest taking a look at the Laravel docs, in particular the Storage Facade https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/filesystem

Comment: Poster did not do his research